Is entropy constant when no heat is transferred?
Does entropy remain constant in when no heat is transferred between the system and surroundings?
If I do only mechanical or electrical work to change the properties like the volume of the system, would entropy be affected?
Because I understand entropy as the number of possible arrangements of atoms in a system. The following is sourced from the book - Physical chemistry by Atkins and Paula

The above picture displays transfer of heat in an exothermic reaction which causes thermal motion in surroundings.

The above picture shows mechanical work done by the system on the surroundings.
Now that got me thinking, if the atoms move in an "organized way", won't the final and initial state of entropy of the system remain constant?

Review this search site:stackexchange.com Entropy change isolated system

Might want to state which book is "this book" (provide a citation).

Entropy is constant if the process is reversible and no heat is exchanged

Entropy is a state function so it does not matter how one goes from start to end only the starting and ending conditions matter. (Just like potential energy, its always the same at the top of a hill no matter how you get there). To calculate $\Delta S$ always use $\Delta S=q_{rev}/T$ so imagine for example  isothermally expanding a gas into a vacuum from $V_1\to V_2$ then a reversible path gives $q_{rev}=nR\ln(V_2/V_1)$ for $n$ moles and so you find the change in entropy.

@porphyrin Bridgman would strongly disagree with you, see, https://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.22.56.

In my comment above I used an isothermal example and should have used an adiabatic one. In the case of a reversible expansion of an ideal gas $q=q_{rev}=0$ and so $\Delta S=0$. This is because the increase in entropy due to the spread of molecules into space is perfectly compensated for by the decreased spread of molecular energy as the temperature falls due to expansion. Buck Thorn gives the equation. In the irreversible case the balance no longer applies. Now $q=Q_{irrev}=0$ and as $Q_{rev} \gt q_{irrev}$, $q_{rev}\gt 0$ thus in this case $\Delta  S \gt 0$.

@hyportnex about what ?

@porphyrin about that in general "To calculate $\Delta S$ always use $\Delta =q_{rev}/T$" because in general there is no $q_{rev}$ always. This is because there are certain inherently irreversible processes in which one can define entropy change, such as plastic deformation or ferromagnetism, etc., see Bridgman for details.

@hyportnex I don't see why plastic deformation cannot be made reversible.

@porphyrin Bridgman:"...But it is safe to say that the majority of actual processes are irreversible, and worse still, most of the objects of daily life, such as a plastically strained metal exhibiting hysteresis, are completely surrounded by irreversibility, it being impossible to leave the present state of the body by any path whatever that is not irreversible in detail. The
classical entropy concept is thus a concept which is applicable only to a highly idealized set of conditions and is not applicable, in principle, to the commonest situations of daily life."

@hypostnex Thermodynamics works perfectly well and is still used because it describes the properties of gasses, liquids and much of chemistry in general. But 'plastically strained metal exhibiting hysteresis' is hardly a 'common situation of daily life' so I find it hard to consider that the quote you give is as correct or as general as it is made out to be.

@porphyrin what you call thermodynamics is actually thermostatics, and in the static range besides plastic deformation and heat conduction that are always and everywhere essentially irreversible there are also ferromagnetism (static) and electric resistivity (steady state) as nontrivial and rather common daily examples of essentially irreversible behavior. And when these irreversibilities are coupled to others....

You could recall the adiabatic irreversible expansion process,even there is no heat exchange,the entropy change is larger than zero.

@hyportnex as far as I know, there are several ways to extend the work domain of entropy from the classical equilibrium regime to the near-equilibrium and eventually the far from equilibrium regimes. de Groot, Onsanger, Prigogine, Mazur and a lot of other people did succesfully apply these concepts to non-equilibrium systems without having to invalidate all the previous literature and using it as a valid basis even though it was designed "just" to explain transformations between initial and final states of a system. I would argue that irreversible phenomena are as important as equilibrium ones

@GiuseppeBasile I believe nothing I said would contradict what you wrote; I only pointed out, and quoted Bridgman to the effect, that despite the entropy of very common and important thermodynamic phenomena cannot be calculated between two equilibrium points a la Clausius, still can be calculated by other almost classical ways. Read Bridgman!

@hyportnex yeah, I misunderstood the meaning of your comment, guess I should re-read comments in the morning and not at 00.00 as my usual! Very interesting reading for what concerns Bridgman!

Also, nowadays there are statistical mechanics methods for situations where classical entropy à la Clausius fails to give any meaningful results. I suggest any interested reader get acquainted with Tsallis Entropy and Non-Extensive Statistical Mechanics; it is both a fascinating and quite useful branch!


Does Entropy remain constant in when no heat is transferred between the system and surroundings?

The absence of a heat transfer does not guarantee that the entropy change of the system is zero. The following expression of the second law of thermodynamics refers to an exchange under reversible conditions:
$\text{d} S = \frac{\text{d}q_\text{rev}}{T}$
The general case
$\text{d} S \ge \frac{\text{d}q}{T}$
leaves it unclear whether the entropy change is zero unless it is known that the process is in fact reversible.
In other words, an adiabatic process can result in a change in the entropy of the system if it is performed irreversibly.
The differential form for a pure substance (absent work other than mechanical)
$\text{d} S  = \frac{C_V}{T}  \text{d} T +  \left( \frac{\partial p}{\partial T} \right)_V\text{d}V$
indicates that an increase in T tends to increase S, as does an increase in V provided $\left( \frac{\partial p}{\partial T} \right)_V \ge 0$. For an ideal gas $\left( \frac{\partial p}{\partial T} \right)_V = \frac{nR}{V}\gt 0$. In a reversible adiabatic process these contributions cancel, whereas in the irreversible case they don't. Compression work during a reversible adiabatic process results in a higher temperature ("more disorder") but also in a smaller volume ("less disorder").
Work and heat are ways of transferring energy to or from a system. However it is how processes ultimately change how energy is distributed through a sytem that matters. Compressing results in less ways of distributing energy, whereas increasing temperature creates more ways.
